# Setting up Spatie Permissions in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-permission

I am facing an issue in setting up the Spite Permissions within my Laravel App

I have followed the following guide https://medium.com/@miladev95/step-by-step-guide-to-user-role-and-permission-tutorial-in-laravel-10-1fecdabfdea0 and I get the following error when running the db:seed

```
  BadMethodCallException 

  Call to undefined method App\Models\Role::givePermissionTo()

  at vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Traits\ForwardsCalls.php:67
     63▕      * @throws \BadMethodCallException
     64▕      */
     65▕     protected static function throwBadMethodCallException($method)
     66▕     {
  ➜  67▕         throw new BadMethodCallException(sprintf(
     68▕             'Call to undefined method %s::%s()', static::class, $method
     69▕         ));
     70▕     }
     71▕ }

  i   Bad Method Call: Did you mean App\Models\Role::getRelation() ?

  1   vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Traits\ForwardsCalls.php:36
      Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::throwBadMethodCallException("givePermissionTo")

  2   vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model.php:2334
      Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::forwardCallTo(Object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder), "givePermissionTo")
```

This is my User Model

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;
use Spatie\Permission\Traits\HasRoles;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable;
    use HasRoles;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for serialization.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast.
     *
     * @var array<string, string>
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
        'password' => 'hashed',
    ];

    public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class);
    }

    public function permissions()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Permission::class);
    }
}
```

I ensured I had the use HasRole within the User Model as required.

My RoleSeeder is as follows:

```
namespace Database\Seeders;

use App\Models\Role;
use Illuminate\Database\Console\Seeds\WithoutModelEvents;
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class RoleSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     */
    public function run(): void
    {
        //
        $adminRole = Role::create(['guard_name' => 'super-admin', 'name' => 'super-admin']);
        $userRole = Role::create(['guard_name' => 'user', 'name' => 'user']);

        $adminRole->givePermissionTo('all');
    }
}
```

Any help would be great

Comment: what does your `Role` model extend from? does it use any special traits? as that method you are trying to call isn't from Eloquent

Comment: @lagbox The following is in my Role Model
`<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Role extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
}
`

Comment: well you are missing that functionality that would come from extending a different class or using a trait ... please refer to the laravel-permissions documentation instead of this blog post ... that trait you are 'using' on the User model `HasRoles` already defines a `roles` relationship and that package has its own `Role` model which uses a trait that gives the `givePermissionTo` method ... this blog article is not good

Comment: You need to use the HasPermissions trait in your Role model.

Answer (score 1):

if you are going to use your own Role model instead of package's model, you should extend your model with package model

```
use Spatie\Permission\Models\Role as SpatieRole;

class Role extends SpatieRole{


}
```

then in permission.php config file u need to change the model that package using.

```
return [

'models' => [
        'role' => \App\Models\Role::class,
  ]
    .....
  ];
```